# How to check for specific strings in files of a large directory

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I have a rather large directory, and I like to search the files for occurrence of specific strings. I have a list of about 30 strings, and my directory is 1.3G. I tried adding all the strings to a file called

```
strings
```

Then I used `grep -r -f strings . > grepresults`
But it takes a loooooong time. And I would not complain except I took a peek into the `grepresults` file, and the content does not seem to match any of my strings. I am doing something wrong. What should I do to see the result of my command immediately, and verify that it is what I want. Then I have no issue letting it run. Please let me know, and I'll post a sample of what it sends currently.

I issued `grep -rFf foo -o` and seems to get a whole bunch of irrelevant content. I do not know how to use stdout. Could you provide more detailed instructions please?

Comment: If the strings are patterns themselves then use `grep -rFf strings .` to treat them as fixed strings..also `strings` is not a good name for a file as there is an executable named `strings`..

Comment: @heemayl - Thanks. I get a similar result. It seems like it is matching everything. Is it somehow creating a file to process perhaps later? The output looks like none of the strings;-(

Comment: Perhaps there are only "source" files that should be searched. Then use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/), a.k.a. *beyond grep*

Comment: You could a) simply use the output form `stout`, i.e. not redirecting it to a file and aborting it, and b) use the -o option to see how your strings are interpreted in the matches.

Comment: Might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/13913220/3701431

Comment: Also , sorting the contents of files might help

Comment: @Serg - Thanks. I sorted the file foo. Moved the content to bar. And I am issued 'LC_ALL=C fgrep -rFf bar'. I do not see anything as output. Is there some way to see that command is at least checking a file or directory or something? I am not sure if my machine is not powerful enough, or my command is wrong.

Comment: You probably don't want to place the output file in the directory you are searching.  Also, when you redirect to a file, stdout is getting buffered, so you will see output in chunks that are the size of the file system block.

Comment: @ user3188445 - Thanks. I think that is why the command takes a while. Allright; I'll put the output file in the parent directory. Please let me know if there is any issue with that.

Comment: "What should I do to see the result of my command immediately, and verify that it is what I want?"  Duplicate of [Keep stdout on screen and in file](http://superuser.com/q/145609/354511).

Comment: Use `tee` to see output that is going to the file. e.g. `… | tee grepresults`

Comment: Should be no problems putting the results in an different (non child) directory. Putting it in to same directory has caused it to be part of the input set, and then grep will loop for ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(Extracted answer from edit)</sub>

I got the result of the search by letting it run overnight. The command I used was:

```
@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/LC_ALL=C fgrep -rFf bar > ~/myfile
```

Moving the results file, called `myfile` in the above command, definitely helped.

I also sorted the strings in the file. It was originally called `strings`, and I learned from one of the comments in this thread to change it to another name. So in the above command it is called `bar`. Using `LC_ALL=C` and `fgrep` instead of `grep` helped immensely. All the suggestions contributed to the answer.